# How to send to laravel request with api prefix?

Tags: laravel, nginx

```
location @laravelapi {
        rewrite /api/(.*)?$ /api/index.php?$is_args$args last;
}
```

When we try access to api/routeexample, laravel gets only routeexample part, and throws 404 error. How we can send full url including 'api' part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm just added

```
include "api.php";
```

into my routes/web.php as hotfix, but i will search for better solution

Answer (score 0):

I m adding an example of how we define route for API request:

In routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
Route::post('api_request', [App\Http\Controllers\YourController::class, 'targeted_function_name'])->name('api_request');
```

});